# Error in running "Cordova run android"

Tags: android, cordova

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Program Files\android-sdk_r24.4.1-windows\android-sdk-windows
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

**Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT**

Please help

Answer (score 0):

there is one of two things first you sould
right click on my computer -properties-advanced system settings-advances-environment variables and set a path to 
ANDROID_HOME with the path of your sdk
and 
Path with the path of your jdk
close the terminal and reopen it it should work well